# TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime

Tags: pandas, date, datetime

The problem is somewhat simple. My objective is to compute the days difference between two dates, say A and B.

These are my attempts:

```
df['daydiff'] = df['A']-df['B']

df['daydiff'] = ((df['A']) - (df['B'])).dt.days

df['daydiff'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['A'])-pd.to_datetime(df['B'])).dt.days
```

These works for me before but for some reason, I'm keep getting this error this time:

> TypeError: class 'datetime.time' is not convertible to datetime

When I export the df to excel, then the date works just fine. Any thoughts?

Comment: This one does not work ?(pd.to_datetime(df['A'])-pd.to_datetime(df['B'])).dt.days

Comment: @Wen for some reason I can't even apply pd.to_datetime.  The error would be class 'datetime.time' is not convertible to datetime

Comment: Then we need see the sample data my friend

Comment: The date is pretty typical in my case:  1/12/2017

Comment: Can you print the head of your data?

Comment: the "A" date: 2016-07-14 and "B" date: 2014-07-01 00:00:00

Comment: Ahh.  I see the problem now.  The pd.to_datetime can't be applied to "B" date

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use pd.Timestamp to handle the awkward differences in your formatted times.

```
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(pd.Timestamp)  # will handle parsing
df['B'] = df['B'].apply(pd.Timestamp)  # will handle parsing
df['day_diff'] = (df['A'] - df['B']).dt.days
```

Of course, if you don't want to change the format of the df['A'] and df['B'] within the DataFrame that you are outputting, you can do this in a one-liner.

```
df['day_diff'] = (df['A'].apply(pd.Timestamp) - df['B'].apply(pd.Timestamp)).dt.days
```

This will give you the days between as an integer.

Comment: thanks!  However, I still get TypeError: Cannot convert input [00:00:00] of type <class 'datetime.time'> to Timestamp :(

Comment: Can you call .dtypes on your dataframe? Have you got mixed types?

Comment: @TylerNG hey I am wondering how you got this to work? I am having a similar issue (TypeError: Cannot convert input [11:00:00] of type <class 'datetime.time'> to Timestamp) in trying to solve my own different problem. Thanks!

Comment: <class 'ellipsis'> is not convertible to datetime
For me this is getting shown

Answer (score 3):

When I applied the solution offered by emmet02, I got **TypeError: Cannot convert input [00:00:00] of type**  as well. It's basically saying that the dataframe contains missing timestamp values which are represented as [00:00:00], and this value is rejected by `pandas.Timestamp` function.

To address this, simply apply a suitable missing-value strategy to clean your data set, before using

```
df.apply(pd.Timestamp)
```

Comment: There is no way to make `.apply(pd.Timestamp)` work, at least with Python 1.1.2

Comment: @linello I hope you mean Pandas 1.1.2, because if you are using Python 1.1.... WELCOME TO THE FUTURE! We have Python 3.9!