# How do i subtarct 2 time columns with each other in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a column Start and HT where both are Object Datatype:
The output which is needed is (HT - Start) in minutes.

I try to convert them to datetime through pd.to_datetime but it throws error
TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime

| Start | HT |
| --- | --- |
| 09:30:00 | 09:40:00 |
| 09:30:00 | 09:36:00 |
| 09:30:00 | 09:50:00 |
| 09:30:00 | 10:36:00 |

Expected Output

| Start | HT | diff(in minutes) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 09:30:00 | 09:40:00 | 10 |
| 09:30:00 | 09:36:00 | 6 |
| 09:30:00 | 09:50:00 | 20 |
| 09:30:00 | 10:36:00 | 66 |

Please help.

Comment: See the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49389358/typeerror-class-datetime-time-is-not-convertible-to-datetime).

Comment: You shouldn't have to convert but simply do subtraction directly on two columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fisrt convert dates using [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

```py
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time.apply(str)
df['HT'] = pd.to_datetime(df['HT'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time.apply(str)
df['diff(in minutes)'] = (pd.to_timedelta(df['HT']) - pd.to_timedelta(df['Start'])).dt.total_seconds() / 60
print(df)
```

You can simplify the above code using [`pd.to_timedelta()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html)

```py
df['Start'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Start'])
df['HT'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['HT'])
df['diff(in minutes)'] = (df['HT'] - df['Start']).dt.total_seconds() / 60
print(df)
```

---

```
      Start        HT  diff(in minutes)
0  09:30:00  09:40:00              10.0
1  09:30:00  09:36:00               6.0
2  09:30:00  09:50:00              20.0
3  09:30:00  10:36:00              66.0
```